# Реализация чата: Ajax / ajax long pooling / WebSockets - разница?

Tags: ajax, websocket, чат, long-poll

Если создать чат на ajax, то нагрузка будет огромной. При 1000 онлайн пользователей это 1000 запросов к БД в секунду.

Каким будет выигрыш в производительности, если использовать:

1. Ajax long pooling
2. WebSockets

Разъясните простым языком, каким образом и **на сколько** будет выигрыш? Я совсем не понимаю обе эти технологии, неужели запросов к БД будет меньше?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ajax

   - Есть, что нового?
   - Нет.
   - Есть, что нового?
   - Нет.
   - Есть, что нового?
   - Нет.
2. Long pooling
   - Есть, что нового?
   - Подожди. Нет.
   - Есть, что нового?
   - Подожди. Нет.
   - Есть, что нового?
   - Подожди. Нет.
3. WebSockets
   - Тут тебе сообщение пришло

Comment: А во время "подожди" что-то происходит? Если нет, то как это отличается от ajax c таймером в 30 секунд, а если да, то во время "подожди" все равно происходит цикл обращений к БД со стороны php?

Comment: @АндрейДиневич У сервера может существовать возможность получения информации о новых сообщениях без циклического опроса базы. Например, всякие DB_ALERTS

Comment: А в случае с WebSockets сообщения в базу данных записывать при каждой отправке? Или при дисконнекте как-то реализовать запись в БД

Comment: @АндрейДиневич Собщения в базу записываются при каждой отправке, чтобы их сразу видели другие пользователи. Как их передавать **на** сервер : через сокеты или аяксом - это не имеет большой разницы